# Do fictional superheroes exist in The Boys?

Tags: the-boys, the-boys-2019

It appears that in the TV series *The Boys*, the superheroes started in the 70s.   And I have heard that the backstory goes back to WWII in the case of the comic books (although I haven't read them).   But this is not as far back as the advent of superheroes in the real world.

It is also clear that at least some popular culture references are the same in the *The Boys* universe (e.g. Spice Girls, Tara Reid, and Billy Zane).

So to what extent does the notion of fictional superheroes exist in these universes?  Are there Superman and Batman and other heroes who predate the "real" superheroes?  Are there other "fictional" superheroes created before or after the existence of the "real" ones?

Comment: They should read Pirate comics.

Comment: It seems to me the existence of real superheroes would severely lessen the impact of comic books about fictional superheroes -- it would be hard to sell comic books about Superman when a real superman, with, compared to the original from the 1940s, actually greater powers, existed. And Batman, who lacked superpowers, would be even less interesting.

Comment: @releseabe:  Possible, but it's not like fictionalized versions of real-world things don't exist in fiction for drama or allegory.  For example, there's no shortage of stories about fictional politicians (House of Card, West Wing, Veep, Designated Survivor, Madam Secretary,......)

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Superman as he was originally portrayed would no longer have worked, as I said. They could I guess have comic books about fictional superheroes but how interesting would they be compared to actual stories about real ones? Anyway, this is "meta-speculative" or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: @releseabe:   Just like Homelander is an obvious re-fictionalized version of Superman, I don't see why there wouldn't be stories about an obvious fictionalized version of a real Homelander.    Art comments on life.

Answer (score 4):

In the comics, the Vought Corporation makes money by releasing comics which give fictionalized or fabricated accounts of the exploits of superheroes in Vought's employ. These comics also form part of Vought's propaganda machine which allows them to make the supes seem good and heroic, when in actuality they are mostly vice-ridden and corrupt.

As for superhero comics that portray fictional (in-universe) heroes, I don't recall any mention of them in either the books or the show.

Comment: Several of the comics also feature the exploits of superheroes known to be dead.